# How do I connect my RPi to university Wifi?

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3

I have changed the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf using tutorials on the web.  But no connections.  I am using a Pi 3.

Comment: Which tutorial have you followed? Are you doing this by command-line or can you use a GUI?

Comment: does you university have a guide for connecting to their wifi? sometimes they use ipsec or other creepy stuff... what OS are you using?